# Как узнать размер файла в конфигурации дебаг и рилиз?

Tags: visual-c++, отладчик

Как узнать размер файла в конфигурации дебаг(релиз)?(Visual Studio)

Comment: Какого файла?..

Comment: @Zergatul , cpp, если Вы об этом. Обычная консоль на С.